# How to check if coordinates are in water and output be true or false?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm working with turbines and when a turbine gets placed in water I want to check if the coordinates of the turbine is true for water.

Using Cesium and open street maps.

I am new to Overpass QL and when I wanted to check if a coordinate matches for water I can't figure out how to script that.

is it possible to check for a node (the coordinates) inside of a bbox way(all water) ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. You'll have to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve to get a good answer for this question. What have you tried, what is the context, what software are you using apart from overpass (it's not clear how this is related to the question). Etc. If you add this someone may be able to help.

Comment: You can also take the tour: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Intersect the coordinates with some data for water features and add an attribute "True" for the ones that intersect?

Comment: There's no meaningful way to do this via Overpass for arbitrary locations (that's what I have to assume, as your question is very unprecise with this respect). Think about coastlines and middle of the ocean. Bottom line is: you need to look for some alternative approach.

Comment: Extract *all* water features from OSM (coastlines, lakes and reservoirs, rivers and riverbanks including islands etc.). Then perform appropriate spatial queries.

Comment: @scai,  mmd,  jbalk , thank you very much for your ideas I will try these and update you guys later on.

Comment: I want to extract boundary box or geometry of all the water and then check if my coordinates are inside of it.
If I have to keep checking if its inside all of the water this will get really heavy and slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a summary of what you need to do.

- Get land polygons (non-sea areas) from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons. If your point is NOT in one of these polygons it's in the sea. If it is in one of the polygons, it might be land, but it might be in a lake or a river, so:
- Get lakes and riverbanks from OpenStreetmap data intersecting your target area. Check whether your point is in one of these.

You'll need to study up on the data formats, of course. That's the hard part.